# ¿Cómo obtener el mes anterior en una consulta SQL de un mes ya seleccionado?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy trabajando en un procedimiento almacenado que de momento así lo tengo realizado:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_NIVELES(
@NIVEL VARCHAR(15),
@MES VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
     IF @NIVEL = 'LINEA MC'
        BEGIN
            SELECT LINEAMC, MES, SUM(MONTODEBITOFLOAT) AS SUMA_DEBITO, SUM(MONTOCREDITOFLOAT) AS SUMA_CREDITO, SUM(MONTODEBITOFLOAT) - SUM(MONTOCREDITOFLOAT) AS TOTAL
            FROM PRUEBAOPEX
            WHERE MES = @MES
            GROUP BY LINEAMC, MES

        END
ELSE
        RAISERROR('EL NIVEL ESCRITO NO EXISTE DENTRO DE LA HOJA DE ARCHIVO', 16, 1)
END
```

El siguiente procedimiento almacenado me muestra la siguiente consulta:

```
EXEC SP_NIVELES 'LINEA MC', 'Febrero'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Viendo el procedimiento, utilizo dos parámetros. El primero la línea que solicito (LINEA MC) y el segundo el nombre del mes. ¿Existe alguna manera en dónde además de la primera consulta (Febrero), me muestre los datos del mes anterior (Enero)? ¿Qué debería cambiar?

Comment: Estás guardando solo el nombre del mes? Como sabes a que año pertenece?

Comment: Tengo una columna que me almacena los años, de tipo Int. En el mes me almacena los textos de los meses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los datos de tipo fecha, deberían de tener columnas de tipo fecha, porque hay funciones específicas para el tratamiento de este tipo de datos. No es una buena práctica utilizar varchar para esto.

Además en el escenario, que está del todo incompleto, expresas muy poco y en la consulta, no indicas nada del año. ¿Que pasa si el mes es enero? ¿Qué pasa si para el més anterior no hay datos? ¿Qué columnas tienen que mostrar estos datos (Todas, solo el total)?

Te voy a dar un acercamiento a lo que solicitas para que puedas ir trabajando un poco.

```
CREATE TABLE PRUEBAOPEX (LINEAMC VARCHAR(20), MES VARCHAR(20), MONTODEBITOFLOAT FLOAT, MONTOCREDITOFLOAT FLOAT)

INSERT INTO PRUEBAOPEX (LINEAMC, MES, MONTODEBITOFLOAT, MONTOCREDITOFLOAT)
VALUES
('505130-EXPENSES','ENERO',10.11,20.5),
('505130-EXPENSES','ENERO',20.23,10.5),
('505130-EXPENSES','ENERO',10.45,0),
('505130-EXPENSES','FEBRERO',30.21,17.5),
('505130-EXPENSES','FEBRERO',40.23,15.5),
('505130-EXPENSES','FEBRERO',50.45,11);
```

Solo inserto datos para enero y febrero.

Si el més filtrado es Febrero:

```
DECLARE @MES VARCHAR(10) = 'FEBRERO'
 DECLARE @MESANT VARCHAR(10);
 SELECT @MESANT = CASE @MES 
                            WHEN 'ENERO' THEN 'DICIEMBRE'
                            WHEN 'FEBRERO' THEN 'ENERO'
                            WHEN 'MARZO' THEN 'FEBRERO'
                            WHEN 'ABRIL' THEN 'MARZO'
                            WHEN 'MAYO' THEN 'ABRIL'
                            WHEN 'JUNIO' THEN 'MAYO'
                            WHEN 'JULIO' THEN 'JUNIO'
                            WHEN 'AGOSTO' THEN 'JULIO'
                            WHEN 'SEPTIEMBRE' THEN 'AGOSTO'
                            WHEN 'OCTUBRE' THEN 'SEPTIEMBRE'
                            WHEN 'NOVIEMBRE' THEN 'OCTUBRE'
                            WHEN 'DICIEMBRE' THEN 'NOVIEMBRE'
                    END;
 
 SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT LINEAMC, MES, SUM(MONTODEBITOFLOAT) AS SUMA_DEBITO,
                          SUM(MONTOCREDITOFLOAT) AS SUMA_CREDITO, 
                          SUM(MONTODEBITOFLOAT) - SUM(MONTOCREDITOFLOAT) AS TOTAL
            FROM PRUEBAOPEX
            WHERE MES = @MES
            GROUP BY LINEAMC, MES
            ) DATA
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
        SELECT LINEAMC, MES, SUM(MONTODEBITOFLOAT) AS SUMA_DEBITO,
                              SUM(MONTOCREDITOFLOAT) AS SUMA_CREDITO, 
                              SUM(MONTODEBITOFLOAT) - SUM(MONTOCREDITOFLOAT) AS TOTAL
                FROM PRUEBAOPEX
                WHERE MES = @MESANT
                GROUP BY LINEAMC, MES
        ) AS DATAANT ON DATA.LINEAMC = DATAANT.LINEAMC 
            AND DATA.MES = @MES 
            AND DATAANT.MES = @MESANT
```

[image: RES1]

La misma ejecución con enero.

[image: Res2]

La idea es simple. Se hace la consulta para el més parámetrizado. Se repite la consulta para el mes anterior. Luego se unen ambas consultas, ya que solo pueden tener una fila, mes y lineaMc, por LineaMc donde el primer conjunto tenga de mes el valor de la variable de entrada y el segundo el anterior.

Remarco, que no es un buen camino, el escogido.